# LINQ Query Filtering for Gender

Tags: vb.net

so recently I was learning about LINQ Query in Visual Basic and I had a question that asks me to filter gender with given three options (Male, Female & All) using a Combo Box. I managed to do something like this:

```
    If cboGender.Text = "All" Then
        rs = From cust In db.Customers
             Where cust.Name.Contains(txtName.Text)
             Select cust
    Else
        rs = From cust In db.Customers
             Where cust.Name.Contains(txtName.Text) And cust.Gender = cboGender.Text
             Select cust
    End If
```

However I wanted to know if there is more effecient way of writing this, maybe not use of If Statements? I am down for any suggestions, thank you for the help

Comment: More efficient in what terms? The `If`is certainly the most efficient approach in terms of CPU or memory. You want a more concise version with less repetition?

Comment: @Rango this is what is stated in the question example: https://i.imgur.com/8Emg5xJ.png . Since it says "Dim rs = ", I assumed there is another way ?

Answer (score 2):

Using rs as an `IQueryable` you can eliminate the entire branch of the if statement

```
 rs = From cust In db.Customers
      Where cust.Name.Contains(txtName.Text)
      Select cust 

If cboGender.Text != "All" Then
     rs = rs Where cust.Gender = cboGender.Text Select cust
End If
```

if this was C#
then

```
rs = cboGender.Text != "All" ?  rs Where cust.Gender = cboGender.Text  Select cust : rs ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a little bit more readable:

```
   rs = From cust In db.Customers
         Where cust.Name.Contains(txtName.Text) AndAlso 
               (cust.Gender = cboGender.Text OrElse cboGender.Text = "All")
         Select cust
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Worked too :D